# Date Input Field in CP View

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, module, development

Is it possible to have a date input field in a control panel view page?

Is there any kind of build in javascript library for the date calendar etc?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: Hi Derek. Expression Engine 3.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `display_field()` method of the first party Date fieldtype. The key thing is to use a text input with a `rel="date-picker"` attribute, but there are a few other things that need to be loaded, depending on where in the CP you are displaying it (some language strings, for example).

Comment: Thank you Derek. I have taken a look at the date fieldtype and see the display_field() function, but I don't really understand how I would call this function into my mcp. Would you be able to explain?